# Use New-AzureDeployment to deploy cloud service, But error occurs "The HTTP version specified is not supported for this operation by the server"

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, powershell-cmdlet, autodeploy

PS C:> New-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "TestAutoDeploy" -Slot "Production" -Package "d:\builds\a.cspkg" -Configuration
 "d:\builds\a.cscfg" -Label "MyDeployment"

New-AzureDeployment : The HTTP version specified is not supported for this operation by the server.
At line:1 char:20
+ New-AzureDeployment <<<<  -ServiceName "TestAutoDeploy" -Slot "Production" -Package "d:\builds\a.cspkg" -Configuratio
n "d:\builds\a.cscfg" -Label "MyDeployment"
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureDeployment], StorageServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.NewAzureDeploymentCom
   mand

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give us a little more background on your problem so we can help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set your subscription details by calling Set-AzureSubscription before trying to do operations in a subscription:

```
$certPath = "cert:\LocalMachine\MY\<your management cert's thumbprint>"
$azure_cert = get-item $certPath

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Your Subcription Name" -SubscriptionId "azure_sub_id" -Certificate $azure_cert -CurrentStorageAccount "azure_storage"
```

read more here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554332.aspx

**EDIT**:  Package cannot be a local file. Specify the path or URI to a .cspkg blob in a storage within the same subscription/project.

Comment: Hi viperguynaz,
   Thanks for you reply,
I have used the command Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile to import publishSettings file
And Call Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName "xxxxxxxxxx" -CurrentStorageAccount "xxxxxxx", to set default storage account. 
The function "New-AzureService" and "Remove-AzureService" are working fine.
It seems storage service doesn't support the operation

Comment: Updated answer, -Package needs to specify a Blob in same subscription/project.

Comment: Correct, It seems doesn't support local file, I have upload cspkg to blob, them execute the command, it success. Thanks for your help

Comment: [Old MS example powershell script](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/) shows using a local path for New-AzureDeployment.

However, I ran into the same HTTP error as OP. I suspect it has to do with  changes to the blob API since that example (such as HTTPS now being mandatory).